# Locating uploaded file with Rspec 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, carrierwave

I am trying to locate my last uploaded file (using Carrierwave) and run the `have_dimensions` method on it with Rspec.

At the moment my test results in a failure , the error is

```
 Failure/Error: expect(@uploader.large_animal_image).to have_dimensions(555, 365)
 Errno::ENOENT:
   No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
```

My test looks like this (tried following the example on their github page but the file upload didn't work as expected)

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'carrierwave/test/matchers'

describe AnimalImage do 
  include CarrierWave::Test::Matchers

  before(:each) do
   AnimalImageUploader.enable_processing = true
    @animal = FactoryGirl.create(:image)
    @uploader = AnimalImageUploader.new(@animal, :image)
    ap(@uploader)
    @uploader.store!
  end

  after(:each) do
   @uploader.remove!
   AnimalImageUploader.enable_processing = false
 end

 context 'Image Versions' do

  it 'should scale large_animal_image to 555 x 365 ' do
   expect(@uploader.large_animal_image).to have_dimensions(555, 365)
  end
 end    
end
```

`ap(@uploader)` outputs

```
#<AnimalImageUploader:0x000000080ae738 @model=#<AnimalImage id: 50, animal_id: nil, image: "yp2.jpg", created_at: "2014-10-10 07:41:20", updated_at: "2014-10-10 07:41:20">, @mounted_as=:image>
```

And it creates the following files

```
/support
  /animal_image
   /image
    /50
     yp2.jpg
     large_animal_image_yp2.jpg
```

How can i access those files to run the `have_dimensions` method on them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok so solved this by figuring out what `@uploader.store!` does (silly me)

I needed to store my file

```
before(:each) do
 AnimalImageUploader.enable_processing = true
 file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/yp2.jpg")
 @animal = AnimalImage.create!(image: file)
 @uploader = AnimalImageUploader.new(@animal, :image)
 @uploader.store!(file)
end
```